# How can allow an ssh connection only over vpn

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn, ufw

I install OpenVPN on my server following this guide --> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

I also setup a firewall with ufw where I add rule to allow ssh connection only from my interal IP assign to me after the VPN is Active.

I cannot connect to my server with this configuration, with or without VPN. What can I do to configure the network to allow ssh connection ONLY over VPN tunnel?

Comment: For ufw, see also https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ufw-allow-incoming-ssh-connections-from-a-specific-ip-address-subnet-on-ubuntu-debian/

Answer (score 1):

You can control it using the ListenAddress directive available in your ssh daemon config file

Something Like

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Reach the line:

```
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

Uncomment if necessary, and edit it accordingly to your vpn configuration,  something like:

```
ListenAddress 10.10.0.1
```

Restart the daemon

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Check if it works

Keep in mind you can also tune your firewall rules to further restrict access to certain subnet / ports, in this case your vpn network

Hope it helps